# How is passing a string literal to a function handled in C++?

Tags: c++, string, call-by-value

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void consumeString(std::string str){
  /* some code */
}

void passStringObject(){
  std::string stringObject = "string literal";
  consumeString(stringObject);
}

void passStringLiteral(){
  consumeString("string literal");
}
```

Now consider the following two cases:

1) The function `passStringObject()` is called.

2) The function `passStringLiteral()` is called.

In case 1 I would assume that - when calling the function `consumeString` within `passStringObject` - the variable `stringObject` is just passed to the function `consumeString` and (because of call-by-value) the copy constructor of the string class is called so that the parameter str is a copy of the variable `stringObject` which was passed to the function `consumeString`.

But what happens in case 2 when the function `consumeString` is called? Is the (overloaded) assignment operator of the string class (maybe assigning the literal to some "hidden" variable in the background?) implicitly called before calling the copy constructor and copying the value of the "hidden" variable to the parameter `str`?

Comment: a temporary `std::string` instance will be created and used in case 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case 2 the `std::string(const char*)` constructor will be called before the object is passed to `consumeString`, which will then copy the temporary string object.

Answer (score 1):

String literals spawn temporary `std::string` objects.

The lifetime of the temporary object is bound to the C++ instruction which created it.

In the case `std::string stringObject = "string literal";` a constructor from `const char*` is invoked to create an object (which is not temporary).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the string literal, a temporary `std::string` object is created, and then copied to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1 the you are the person who is creating the object, and when the function is called the copy constructor of the string class is called and the string is copied.

In the second case the, parametrized constructor (with `char *` parameter) is called to construct the string object.

in case 2 the destructor string class will be called as soon as the `consumeString` returns, and in first case the destructor will be called twice once for the temperory variable in the `consumeString` function and other for variable in `passStringObject`;

Answer (score 0):

In the case1 the string object is created in the local memory heap and we pass the object to the calling.

In the case2 the string object is created in the stack and that object is passed to the calling function, on return it get deleted automatically